# Help with Wemos D1 project!

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, stepper-motor, adafruit, mini

I am trying to make my first arduino simple project based on the directions of this video for a gift to my fiancee [youtube][https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=duiAbLsXZSE&t=309s&ab_channel=Breaks%27n%27Makes[/youtube]](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=duiAbLsXZSE&t=309s&ab_channel=Breaks%27n%27Makes%5B/youtube%5D).

Suggest you watch it so you can understand better.

I follow his directions exactly but I made one change: I use a WS2811 led strip with a 12V-1A power supply so I power the LED strip from the power supply by soldering it on the step down converter's inputs.

Not to just mention that there is no experience in the soldering part so I've made a bit of a mess.

This is a funny drawing of what I am trying to accomplish: https://pasteboard.co/K0aoZ2A2cSxQ.png

and this is a video of my creation so you can see for yourselves: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SOYLV7v2Txo

So the issue is that after the upload of the sketch to the Wemos D1 mini pro. I plug everything on and just sometimes nothing happens and sometimes just the LED strip is turned on but I have no control via the app. Essentially no connection to wifi. And just like that, I've just "burned" 2 wemos D1 mini pro. Or I think I have because they are not responding when I try to upload a sketch and no LED onboard light turns on.

I want point out that:

The dupont wires on wemos didnt hold that well and I had to balance them out or hold them.

I measured 50 times all the connections (voltage) and seemed fine. I even measured the voltage on the strip itself. 12V on the strip and the input pins of the step down converter and 5V everything else (including data of led strip.)

I am not good at the soldering part yet. Dunno if that's the issue.

Please help me fellow scientists!

- EDIT:
- CODE: https://www.dropbox.com/s/7r52tcwwm6v2i75/LED_Stepper.ino?dl=0
- AND SCHEMATIC OF THE CIRCUIT: [image]

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: please add your code to the post

Comment: From what I know WS2811 and WS2812 strips are **5V**, and according to your schematic you're giving them ***12V***, which will blow them. Also, maybe they blow in a way that it misfires/releases 12V on the data line, which goes DIRECTLY into your Wemos GPIO, killing it too.

Comment: I used the LED strip's own power supply. It's 12V /1A.

Comment: Questions about the application layer of some Arduino stuff are more suited for https://arduino.stackexchange.com/. Here you can ask either about design or troubleshooting of an electrical circuit with a proper electronics schematic. Or you could also ask a completely separate question about soldering advise, with pictures of your attempts. Not all in one single question though, please.